# Setting up Spinnaker on Kubernetes and accessing spinnaker UI

Tags: spinnaker

I have deployed the individual spinnaker components to kubernetes and when I am trying to access spinnaker through http://localhost:9000 I get an empty response from the server. I verified the configuration for clouddriver-local.yml, spinnaker-local.yml and everything seems good. Am i missing anything here? when I am trying to curl localhost:9000, I get an empty response from the server
here is the [kubernetes setup info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDbeP.png)

Comment: Setting up spinnaker is really hard. You have to edit a quite a few files and check if the ones in the experimental folder is in sync with what is in the root /config folder. It is not updated all the time. Also cors settings on the gate component might be needed. Check your browser js console.

Comment: Thank you! got it setup. seems to work fine as well if i pick up credentials (aws) from my local machine but i cant pass it on as secrets to spinnaker for multiple environments

Comment: In my experience, clouddriver can work without a credentials file, using AWS STS and assumeRole. IAM is a bit hard (at least a steep learning curve) to grasp. Front50 need actual key id and secret to work.

Comment: Thank you! Figured out the approach.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Spinnaker has evolved by this time and it should be easier to set up by now. If you want to do PoC only or deploy to small enterprise projects then i suggest you use Armory's [Minnaker](https://github.com/armory/minnaker)

Now if you want to  deploy large projects to a robust and fully enhanced kubernetes cluster then that is a different story and the steps are as it follows:

- Minimum 4 CPUs and 12 GB of memory
- Access to an existing object storage bucket
- Access to an IAM role or user with access to the bucket. (AWS IAM for AWS S3)
- An existing Kubernetes Ingress controller or the permissions to install the NGINX Ingress Controller (ForDeck UI access)

Installation

1. Create a Kubernetes namespace for Spinnaker and Halyard
2. Grant the default ServiceAccount in the namespace access to the cluster-admin ClusterRole in the namespace.
3. Run Halyard (Spinnaker installer) as a Pod in the created namespace (with a StatefulSet).
4. Create a storage bucket for Spinnaker to store persistent configuration in.
5. Create an user (AWS IAM in case of AWS deployment) that Spinnaker will use to access the bucket (or alternately, granting access to the bucket via roles).
6. Rung **hal** client interactively in the Kubernetes Pod:
7. Build out the hal config YAML file (.hal/config)
8. Configure Spinnaker with the IAM credentials and bucket information
9. Turn on other recommended settings (artifacts and http artifact providers: github, bitbucket, etc)
10. Install Spinnaker `hal deploy`
11. Expose Spinnaker (Deck through ingress)

For more details refer to

- [Armory's doc](https://docs.armory.io/spinnaker-install-admin-guides/install-on-k8s/)
- Spinnaker [Distributed installation in Kubernetes](https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/install/environment/#distributed-installation)

Hope the guideline helps